# Tkinter show processing message

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In my new  program, the user gives a non-negative integer number to the program in order to calculate the factorial of this number. But sometimes when the number is large, like 25637, it takes some time to calculate. I want if this time is over than 2 seconds to print a processing message to the Python's shell. Unfortunately I am a new guy to tkinter and I don't know how to do that.
Please can you show me the solution of that I ask in my code in order to understand it?

This is my code:

```
#! usr/bin/python
# Filename: x_Factorial!_GUI.py

import sys, warnings

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    warnings.warn("System FAILURE, Python 3.x is required in order to execute this program",
                  RuntimeWarning)
else:
    version_info_num = str(sys.version_info[0]) + "." + str(sys.version_info[1]) + "." + str(sys.version_info[2])
    print("System SUCCESS, You are currently executing this program on Python's version: {}".format(version_info_num))

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        #Window_Creation
        scr_xloc = int(self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - 800 / 2)
        scr_yloc = int(self.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - 600 / 2 - 30)

        self.geometry("800x600+{}+{}".format(scr_xloc, scr_yloc))
        self.minsize(width = 800, height = 600)

        self.title("x_Factorial!")

        self.configure(bg = "#F06428")

        #Window_Controls
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.Resize_Window)

        self.bind("<F11>", self.Toggle_Fullscreen)
        self.state_mode = False

        self.bind("<Escape>", self.Quit)

        # Widgets_Creation
        self.User_Line_Text = tk.StringVar()
        self.User_Line_Text.set("Please enter a non-negative integer number:")

        self.User_Line = tk.Entry(bg = "#FFFFFF", font  = ("Comic Sans MS", 10, "bold"), fg = "#000000",
                               justify = "left", relief = "flat", textvariable = self.User_Line_Text)

        self.User_Line.place(width = 400, height = 40, x = 200, y = 250)

        self.User_Line.bind("<Button-1>", self.Clear_Text)

        self.User_Line.bind("<Key-Return>", self.Processing)

        self.Output_Box = tk.Text(bg = "#FFFFFF", font  = ("Comic Sans MS", 10, "bold"), fg = "#000000",
                               relief = "flat")

        self.Output_Box.place(width = 600, height = 240, x = 100, y = 320)

    def Clear_Text(self, event):
        self.User_Line.delete("insert", "end")

    def Processing(self, event):
        user_input = str(self.User_Line.get())
        user_input = int(float(user_input))
        import math

        factorial_num = math.factorial(user_input)

        self.Output_Box.delete("1.0", "end")
        self.Output_Box.insert("1.0", str(user_input) + "! = " + str(factorial_num))

    def Resize_Window(self, event):
        self.win_width = int(event.width)
        self.win_height = int(event.height) 

    def Toggle_Fullscreen(self, event):
        self.state_mode = not self.state_mode
        self.attributes("-fullscreen", self.state_mode)

    def Quit(self, event):
        self.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = GUI()
    App.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why the rollback of my edit? The title I gave to your post was a lot more suggestive than your current title. I'm not here editing posts just because I like to put a hand everywhere and because I have a lot of time to waste, but to improve their readability.

Comment: Sorry I confused your edits with my post text

Comment: @K.Leontis: updated my answer -- the problem is not `math.factorial`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpler way is to print the processing message just before the call to factorial -- maybe something like:

```
print('calculating factorial of %d. . . ' % user_input, end='')
```

and once you have the answer:

```
print(factorial_num)
```

However, this will always print.

If you only want to print after two seconds have elapsed then you will need to start a timer thread, have it print after two seconds, or signal it to abort instead if you get your answer back first.  Something like:

```
from threading import Thread
import time


class Timer(Thread):

    abort = False

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        if not self.abort:
            print('Processing...')
```

and then around the `math.factorial` call:

```
    timer = Timer()
    timer.start()
    factorial_num = math.factorial(user_input)
    timer.abort = True
```

Unfortunately, `time.sleep` is not guaranteed to wake up exactly after two seconds, and on my system in doesn't wake up until after the `math.factorial` call is complete, making it useless for me.

---

**Edit**

A little more debugging and I discovered the problem is not the `math.factorial` function -- it can calculate 173,000 in about two seconds on my 5-year-old i7.  The problem is trying to get that number as text in the tkinter window, which is 831,053 digits long (and took 46 seconds to popuulate).

Comment: I want if calculation time has past 2 seconds and calculation isn't complete then start printing processing.